# How do i get the process id of the active window using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, process, pid

Im using Visual Studio 2015 and I would like to get the process id of the active window so for example if my timer1 ticks while firefox is the active window it would get firefox's process id. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! See [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Get+Process+ID+of+active+window+VB.NET) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680356/get-the-process-name-of-the-window-that-is-currently-active-and-in-focus-using-v

Comment: @dejan87 : The same as the first result in the Google search. ;)